# Парсер для SQL-запроса

Tags: c#, парсер, sql

Целый день пытался найти внятное готовое решение, но к большому удивлению, ничего нормального нет. Майкрософтовский, который со Студией DB Edition идёт, не получилось использовать, видимо, потому что мы используем .NET 3.5, там ссылки на некоторые типы не валидны. Простенький парсер, скачанный с Code Project, тоже не годится, мне, собственно, нужно анализировать только блок WHERE, а он умеет только разделять запросы на блоки. General работает не с нормальными строками, а с чем-то дельфийским (ещё и денег за это хотят, обнаглели!). Парсер от какой-то джавовской СУБД, портированной на C#, который можно скачать с Code Project, не компилируется, а на сайте проекта - наружу не торчит.

Сейчас у меня два варианта, что делать.

1. Дизассемблировать сборку System.Data и выцепить из неё код, который строит синтаксическое дерево при обработке свойства DataView.RowFilter.
2. Написать свой парсер. Правда, меня никто этому не учил.

Не знаю, что из этого будет проще и быстрее.

UPD: пока остановился на втором варианте. Лексический анализатор получился довольно легко, а дальше начались проблемы. У меня есть несколько лет назад разработанная отличная объектная модель запроса, но чтобы получить её из списка лексем, требуется синтаксический анализ, и у меня как-то недостаточно знаний, чтобы понять статьи на Википедии на эту тему. С чего надо начинать изучение всех этих автоматов и формальных грамматик, чтобы пришло понимание, что надо делать?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри здесь в комментариях https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589096/parsing-sql-code-in-c-sharp

Comment: Это я смотрел. Ничего из предложенного не работает.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, я частично написал SQL-парсер, выглядящий более по-человечески, чем то, что я видел из готового. Но чтобы завершить эту работу нужен бы какой-нибудь вдохновитель. А то как-то незачем, в рамках той конкретной задачи ограничился простейшим лексическим анализатором, а собственно синтаксический анализатор анализирует не всё.

Возможно, кому-нибудь было бы интересно присоединиться и что-нибудь написать для SQL-парсера на C# с дружественным API.